# center is not defined - <!DOCTYPE html> error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I getting error:

> ReferenceError: center is not defined

and console marks `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Why? Without a parameter in the function call everything is fine. All HTML tags are fine, on top I have `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<button onclick="getRegion(center)" class="btn btn-region">centrum</button>
```

```js
function getRegion(region) {
    var listRegions = { 
        "center": [ '7', '5' ],
        "south": [ '12' ],
        "north": [ '11' ],
        "west": [ '4' ]
    };
    var activeRegion = listRegions[region];

    //remClass();
    for ( var i = 0; i < activeRegion.length; i++ ) {
        $('section.bok-map').find( $('.pl' + activeRegion[i]) ).addClass('active-region');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sending a string literal as the argument, so `center` should be in quotes: `'center'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getRegion(center)` call, `center` needs to be quoted because you want a string.

```
<button onclick="getRegion('center')" class="btn btn-region">centrum</button>
```

Without the quotes, it is treated as a variable called `center` which obviously doesn't exist.